# I have this error while launching the command ./runInstaller

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, redhat

I have this error while launching the command

> ./runInstaller
>
> ./runInstaller: line 95: /home/nsn/Desktop/clusterware/install/.oui: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

You need to be root. run again with `sudo ./runInstaller`

Comment: but they impose to be the oracle user but even this user don't have the permission to in the .oui